# remove pipe delimiter from data using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am new to spark, i am using scala to separate pipe delimited file and save in hdfs without pipe delimited, for that i have written this code.

```
object WordCount {
 def main(args: Array[String])
 {
 val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/xxxx")
 val word = textfile.map( l => l.split("|"))
 word.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxxx/Sparktest")
 }
}
```

but when i am executing it i am not getting any error's but in my hdfs i am getting below data.

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@10ed847f
[Ljava.lang.String;@4316ebe
[Ljava.lang.String;@495d7e18
[Ljava.lang.String;@19017f49
[Ljava.lang.String;@314b9e72
[Ljava.lang.String;@5b8f67a6
[Ljava.lang.String;@23ddf240
[Ljava.lang.String;@404b5a25
[Ljava.lang.String;@130b541d
[Ljava.lang.String;@4cbf45af
[Ljava.lang.String;@21780b86
[Ljava.lang.String;@503c9b94
[Ljava.lang.String;@3b0a3ab3
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong.
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are splitting each string into a Array of Strings. To save as text file, you'll need to use `mkString(",")` if you wish to concatenate with a comma. But I don't see any purpose in that.

If you want to replace pipe separator by a comma, you can use `_.replaceAll("|",",")` instead and save it :

```
val word = textfile.map(_.replaceAll("\\|",",").replaceFirst(",","").trim)
word.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxxx/Sparktest")
```

**PS :** You can replace the comma with anything you want e.g a whitespace, a word, etc.

So ***Why does the pipe need to be escaped ?***

> A string split expects a regular expression argument. An unescaped | is parsed as a regex meaning "empty string or empty string," which isn't what you mean.

Comment: i tried using replaceAll but i am getting this error "error: value replaceAll is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]"

Comment: can you please give the proper example so that i can understand it better.

Comment: now the result i am getting is coming with coma and even pipe is not replaced



before :  |BIN|20121009151949||ORU^R01|120330003918|P|2.2
now: |,B,I,N,|,2,0,1,2,1,0,0,9,1,5,1,9,4,9,|,|,O,R,U,^,R,0,1,|,1,2,0,3,3,0,0,0,3,9,1,8,|,P,|,2,.,2,

Comment: can you give a data sample please ?

Comment: sample :-
|BIN|SMS|BIN|20121009151949||ORU^R01|120330003918|P|2.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118923/discussion-between-captcha-and-eliasah).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.